# AngularJS ng-repeat using $index in a filter

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat and trying to use the $index in a filter like this

```
<div data-ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">            
  <div ng-repeat="student in students | filter:{Surname:'Smith', Group: {{$index}}">
    <span ng-click="updateStudent(student.StudentID)">{{student.FullName}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting a syntax error in the Chrome dev tools console.  Is it possible to use $index like this?

I have also tried Group: $index without the braces

Comment: You're missing `}` at the end of the `ngRepeat`

Comment: Aside from the missing `}` at the end, don't you mean `filter:{Surname:'Smith', Group: i}`?

Comment: Yes I think a combination of both of these is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the double braces here, since you are using `ng-repeat`, but also you were missing a final `}`

```
ng-repeat="student in students | filter:{Surname:'Smith', Group: $index}"
```